# Bosch Induction Stove/Oven slide in tripping 50amp GFCI

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, gfci

Bosch Induction Stove/Oven slide in tripping 50amp GFCI

The induction stove top slide in range is tripping a 50amp GFCI about once a week.

- trips while "off" no load except standby electronics inside and or
  the clock

  never trips under any combination of load, thermal up thermal down
  etc

  dedicated new line nothing shared

  the new 50amp $100 GFCI replaced with another $100 breaker

  Square D homeline - pigtail

I paid and chatted with an electrician and his answer was that the GFCI's don't play well with the new modern induction stoves..... said he has seen this more than 20 times lately. Solution replace with standard breaker.

I saw some extensive discussion in another posting over numerous CAFI breakers randomly tripping over line noise apparently inappropriately interpreted by the breakers, except I have a GFCI (yellow test button).

Any thoughts ? i'm about resolved to accept this is likely similar deal and go back to standard breaker as this in not a new build - I feel sorry for those in new builds and or afaik 2020 code change brought in all the GFCI and CAFI regs for large appliances.

All new circuit from panel to appliance...
Random trip so if I had leakage it would be constant eh ?
No point in trying to megger the line eh ??
I have a 4000v megger I use for testing floor heat cable before it's buried under tile....

Above my pay grade but to megger my cable can that be done with appliance still plugged in ???? I'm not about to cut the sealant at the counter top edge, pull this ill fitting - long story due to floor levelness issues - heavy as hell stove back out unless we get really desperate - NOT desperate just moderately to heavily annoyed LOL.

Thanks.

Comment: Have read older(pre 2009) appliances(fridges) usually have to go back to standard breakers, but newer ones should be designed to play nice with GFCIs.  Just wondering if it picking up a problem with another close circuit, since it is tripping with low power.

Comment: DO NOT MEG THE CABLE WITH THE UNIT CONNECTED!  The electronics are not rated for this high voltage and you may trash your electronics and that’s what induction units are all electronics that do the real work.  I tell my customers if you plan on lots of problems over go with the electronic breakers that are required on plug in devices but there is an exception in my state for installs built in place dedicated circuits don’t require the electronic protection check with your AHJ as I know of several jurisdictions do not adopt this part of the code still only 120v 15&20 and not all of them.

Comment: Just to repeat brand new appliance 2020 , confirmed not megger the line common sense kicked in and asked....., to repeat is tripping about once a week NOT in use - cannot duplicate on demand during use or load

Comment: https://iaeimagazine.org/features/systems/gfci-protection-and-the-2020-nec/   "....dwelling under NEC-2020 require GFCI on any receptacle rated 125-volt through 250-volt that is installed in a GFCI-required location and connected to a single-phase branch circuit rated at 150-volts or less to ground. ,  mean that electric range receptacle outlet needs to be GFCI protected? No, the same rules   if the range receptacle is within six feet of the kitchen sink, then it will require GFCI protection.

Answer (score 1):

> the new 50amp $100 GFCI replaced with another $100 breaker

*cringe* Please seek to avoid doing that.  Generally people leap way too fast to "faulty detection device" and never look earnestly at the possibility of actually having a ground fault.

> I feel sorry for those in new builds and or afaik 2020 code change brought in all the GFCI and CAFI regs for large appliances.

No such requirement exists.  Those are required *in certain  GFCI-required locations* like garages, for 240V *receptacles*... but not hard-wired or fastened-in-place loads, which ranges are generally considered to be.

The usual place this comes up is Electric Vehicle Supply Equipment.  I tell people "you'll want to hardwire that EVSE" to avoid the GFCI problem.  But most of them just bought a Tesla, so it's not like they can't afford a GFCI breaker.

That said, GFCI on a range is a smart way to cope with a legacy 3-wire connection such as "/3 no-ground" or "SE cable".  (it's always been illegal to use "/2 w/ground" since neutral is not ground).   However one could retrofit ground instead, or replace the feed cable (and 6-6-6-6 aluminum is legal most places, and under a buck a foot. Use AL-rated 75C socket and a torque screwdriver.)

---

That said, when a safety device alerts on danger, dealing with that *by murdering the safety device* is precisely as idiotic as it sounds.  I would look for other issues in the wiring, and if none can be found, I'd be pushing back on the appliance maker. UL doesn't approve appliances which trip GFCIs.

Comment: Yes I get that and repeating no immediate trips ever when setting ON or during use, had to rule out the breaker

Comment: Square D took an extensive tech call from me amazingly , breaker good . It's too bad it doesn't hold a memory like the new CAFI breakers hold.  While we had both phases and N detached earlier - I tested for any conintuity across load lines N and G all good. Only thing left I can think of is megger the NEW cable being desperate but will require major job of unsealing and pulling stove.

Comment: Going after manfacturer Bosch for warranty call now. Any other ideas ?